# What is the cause and fix to water slowly coming out of an outdoor faucet when its turned off?

Tags: water, water-pressure

Regardless of how tightly I turn the faucet off, there is water that flows out.  When I attach a hose with a spray nozzle, the water finds a way to leak out either at the faucet where the hose is connected or around the spray nozzle.  There are 4 other outside spigots that are not having the same problem.

Comment: I have a 50 year old home that I bought 2 years ago.  One of the projects was replacing all the outside water valves as the seat in them were too worn to seal correctly.  Every one of them dripped when closed.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "there is water that flows out"?  Do you mean for up to a minute?  Or hours later water is still flowing?

Comment: We'd need to know more about your faucet to help. Your question is too general.

Answer (score 1):

Oops, I think I misunderstood the question.

It sounds like this is a "frostproof" spigot.  If so, there should be a small white plastic cap on the top of the spigot just behind the knob.  A picture would ensure that a proper identification is made.

Most of these spigots can be rebuilt.  However, it may be more efficient (time wise) to replace it (depending on brand, age, availability of suitable parts).  But... this depends on how accessible the body of the valve is in your structure.  Again, a picture is going to help a lot.

Comment: I don't know I think you understood it pretty well. No matter art kind of faucet it is, it is leaking which means it has a worn seat or washer and needs to be rebuilt or replaced. There should be a shut off valve just inside the house to isolate the outside spigot.